# Python - bash integration

Tags: python, bash

I have some bash scripts organized as a menu, that run case options:

```
case "$REPLY" in
    1 )
            $PATH1/script1.bash
            break
            ;;
    2 )
            $PATH2/script2.bash
            break
            ;;
```

Each one of these script run itself other bash scripts.

I need to write a python simple program, that while running, keeps trace of what has been chosen by the user, so the order of the executed bash scripts.

Don't know if it is possible...

Comment: create log file and append it from your bash scripts... IMVHO that is simplest.

Comment: thanks, but bash scripts are alot... I guess if it is faster create a new one without refactor hundreds of scripts.

Comment: _"I guess if it is faster create a new one"_ Refactoring the hundred of scripts will be faster. The only other way that I can think of would be using `inotify`, but it is not simple, not accurate, and you'll need to hardcode the path of the hundred of scripts (= hard to maintain)

Comment: Why do you need Python for this?

Comment: I actually don't need python, I was trying to find a fast way to embed those shell and capture the output call done by each one.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python, or find/grep/sed tooling to edit all that shell scripts. I would use git, but I would also surround my changes with comment. Just in case - later it can be a bit complicated to track many commits - say in 2-3 years.

Reason here is that I don't have a way to do that without touching that scripts. Each script means separate process started, so that should be possible. On the other hand - adding `echo` just after `#!` should not be a big deal - you can add date/time, script name, and all parameters.